# Models not connecting with the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

this was one of our seatworks earlier at school. I don't know php that much and I want to know why my model isn't connecting with my controller.

**Controller**

```
class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("user_model");
    }

    public function login()
    {
        /* Display the login page */
        $this->load->view("form");
        $this->user_model->get_all_users;

    }



    public function validate()
    {
        /* Validate the login details passed via POST parameter.
        If successful, create session and redirect to people list page.
        If failure, redirect to login page. */
        if (isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["password"])) {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];





        }
```

**Model**

```
class user_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }

    public function get_all_users() {

        $res = $this->db->from('account');
        if ($res) {
            return $res->result_array();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function get_user($id) {
        $res = $this->db->from("account")->where("id", $id)->get();
        if ($res) {
            return $res->result_array();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

just like when I use user_model in the controller, It also says that result_array not found in the model. Assuming my database is configured correctly. Can anyone help me with this?

**db settings**

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'correctpassword',
    'database' => 'challenge',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: It should be `$this->user_model->get_all_users();`

Comment: Hello! thanks for helping but my main problem is the controller can't really detect the user_model. I can't retrieve any data from it

Comment: and in your model function replace `  $res = $this->db->from('account');` with `  $res = $this->db->get('account');`

Comment: Unfortunately its still not working. The controller still doesn't recognize the user_model

Comment: what is your model file name? it should be `User_model.php`

Comment: If your controller is not recognizing the model it means model is somewhere else ie,in different folder?

Comment: Oh my bad its now working my IDE is just not recognizing it. Would you happen to have any suggestions on how to access every item for each row in the database? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Thank you so much @NishantNair

Comment: @Jason If I have answered your question please upvote the answer below so that if some one in community searches for answer they can have the verified answer

Comment: Follow the class and file naming method for controllers and models etc as here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: to troubleshoot: print $this->db->last_query();die;

Answer (score 0):

You should give and call to you model method.

Use this

```
$this->user_model->get_all_users();
```

Instead of

```
$this->user_model->get_all_users;
```

Every item of database

```
 foreach ($query->result() as $row)
 {
  echo $row->title;
  echo $row->name;
  echo $row->body;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model use `get` instead of `from`

```
 $res = $this->db->get('account');
```

Comment: Check the controller code properly Model has already been loaded in Constructor

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to use any of CI's helpers, models or other libraries, you need to do this through the CI instance. This is achieved by doing this:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

> You should call your model method in this way.

$this->user_model->get_all_users();

> and make sure you make autoload your model in library

Answer (score 0):

Generally if your working in codeignitor make sure your file name and Class Name are same , it is good practice if you keep the First letter to be capital of controller file and model file , as it might create a problem while running on actual server .

For your problem please do these changes and check and if you have still error please share screenshot in comment

**Controller File**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("user_model", "um");
}
```

**Model File**

Make sure you make Capital First letter of model file and class Name

```
 public function get_all_users() {

    $res = $this->db->select('*') 
                    ->from('account')
                    ->get(); 

    if ($res) {
        return $res->result_array();
    }
    return null;
}
```